# A Short Story from 1978-1980 Read Magazine About 5 Items to Bring into a Survival Bunker

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am hoping to learn the title of a short story from Read Magazine regarding a select few members of society to enter survival bunkers and continue the human race.  The candidates must choose five items to bring with them into their bunkers.  The main character chooses items such as pens and a tape recorder to document his story for future generations.  He will also be provided with a suitable mate to help procreate the human race.  The story ends with a scientist guaranteeing that the items which he chose will, indeed, be secured in the bunker.  However--the surprise ending--the main character neglected to include himself as one of the five items in his list, and will die along with most of humanity.

I recall this short story being in a Read Magazine issue from 1978-1980, when I was in grades 6-7-8.

Hi, SteveV,

Thanks for any help!  I could not find any online archives for Read.  I can pass on to you what I recall, though.  We were allowed to read the magazines in English class every other Friday as a reward for good effort.  We also had them, every now and then, in high school.

I remember wonderful short story adaptations in Read, such as William Hoffman's "The Way Up," Stephen King's "Battleground," and William F. Nolan's "The Underdweller."  Also, in 1978, Read magazine discussed Ralph Bakshi's Lord of the Rings.

I keep an eye out on eBay for back issues of Read.  Perhaps I might come across the very copy that has eluded me.

I know that these musings do not help with my original query, yet I hope to provide a context for other short stories that Read offered students.

Thanks again for all of your help,

Stuart

Comment: It would help (me at least) if you had more information about Read Magazine.  Because of its name, it's hard to google and I don't see it in the isfdb.com magazine list.  Do you have a website?

Comment: @SteveV - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_(magazine)